# What alternatives exist for EOBrowser.exe & LibraryLocator.exe for ArcGIS Desktop 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

> Original Question: Where are the EOBrowser.exe & LibraryLocator.exe tools in the ArcGIS Desktop 10 > Developer Kit?

I went to use LibraryLocator.exe and couldn't find it now that I'm on ArcGIS Desktop 10.  And that's when I realized there is no ArcGIS\DeveloperKit\Tools\ installed.

Do these exist in 10.0? Are they downloadable?  Or is expected that we use the website (*which is what I generally do anyway*)?  The fate of my SlickRun magic word for LibraryLocator.exe will be decided by the answers to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are really not shipped with ArcGIS anymore. I've never really used the Library Locator that much anyway as I've found the **help index** to be a quicker way to look up which library an interface resides in.

As far as EOBrowser is concerned, the good old **OleView.exe** which shipped, for example, with VB6, does the trick just fine. On my system (VS2008 & VS2010, no VB6) it can be found in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin. It can be also downloaded from various places if you search for it.

In case you, like me, find OleView a little rusty, try the [.NET Component Inspector](http://oaklandsoftware.com/product_compinsp1/product_1.html). It is a **free product** which, despite its name, can inspect COM types and COM categories as well and is more stable (though having a few glitches) than both EOBrowser or OleView.